# Why my bind event Return in tkinter is not working? (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

```
from tkinter import *

main_window = Tk ()

main_window.title("Register Form")

frame = Frame (main_window)
frame.pack()

l_name = Label (frame, text = "Name:")
l_name.grid()
e_name = Entry (frame)
e_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

def show_welcome_message(event):
    l_welcome = Label (frame, text = "Welcome, {}".format(e_name.get()))
    l_welcome.grid(row =2, columnspan =2)
    e_name.delete(0,END) #apaga o conteúdo de qualquqer entre box
    
button = Button(frame, text = "Ok")
button.bind("<Return>", show_welcome_message) #<Button-1> comando de clicar com o botão esquerdo do mouse
button.grid(row=1, columnspan =2)

main_window.mainloop()
```

A run the code, type the text and press `Enter` but the welcome message is not apearing.Why this is not working?

Comment: return is for your enter or not? don't bind it to the button. bind it to you entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button needs to have the focus to receive key events. you can set focus to your button to check this. (`button.focus()`)

But I think you should be binding `<Return>` to `Entry` and not the button if you want to show the label when Enter key is pressed after completing the entry.

```
...

e_name = Entry (frame)
e_name.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

def show_welcome_message(event=None):
    l_welcome = Label (frame, text = "Welcome, {}".format(e_name.get()))
    l_welcome.grid(row =2, columnspan =2)
    e_name.delete(0,END) #apaga o conteúdo de qualquqer entre box
    
button = Button(frame, text = "Ok", command=show_welcome_message)
e_name.bind("<Return>", show_welcome_message) 
#<Button-1> comando de clicar com o botão esquerdo do mouse
button.grid(row=1, columnspan =2)
#button.focus()

main_window.mainloop()
```